# Error "ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1239:" while creating the tls secret using pfx cert

Tags: azure, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

I am trying to create the kubernetes secret using PFX certificate that are stored in the keyvalut
I have download the secrets and the certificates to store the secrets

I have followed the below steps to store the secrets but i am getting the below error

```
#To get the password of the certificate
az keyvault secret show --name $secret_name --vault-name $keyvault_name  -o tsv --query value)

#download the certificate
az keyvault certificate download --file $cert_pfx --name $cert_name --vault-name $keyvault_name

#convert pfx to key
Error:

0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1239:
#140546015532944:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:405:Type=PKCS12
```

Any idea? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Use this command to convert the pfx to pem and pfx to key

    `openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out certificate.pem -password pass:XXXX
    openssl  pkcs12 -in certtificate.pfx -nocerts -out private-key.key -password pass:XXXXX `

Answer (score 0):

*I tried to reproduce the same in my work environment and got the expected results as shown in below*

*I have the keyvault with newly created secrets and set the polices to access the secrets*

```
az keyvault set-policy -n "keyvault-name" --spn "service-principal-id" --secret-permissions get
```

[image]

I have created the certificate with the name "policycert"

```
az keyvault certificate create --vault-name newcertkv --name policycert -p "$(az keyvault certificate get-default-policy -o json)"
```

[image]

Added the polices to access the certificate

```
az keyvault set-policy -n newcertkv --spn "spn-id" --certificate-permissions get
```

[image]

Generated the private keyvault and certificate

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > pkeys123.key
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 365 -key pkeys123.key -out newcert123.cert
```

After enter the command it will ask the name and cert related documents
I generated the password using below command

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey pkeys123.key -in newcert123.cert
```

I have conerted this into pfx

```
 $fileContentBytes = get-content ‘newcert123.pfx' -AsByteStream
    [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($fileContentBytes) | Out-File ‘pfx-encoded-bytes.pem
```

The secrets need to be set to PKCS file format

```
az keyvault secret set --vault-name newcertkv --name newcertsecret --file pfx-encoded-bytes.pem --description "application/x-pkcs12"
```

I have downloaded the certificate and converted the pfx to pem and then PFX to key

```
az keyvault certificate download --file newcert123.pem --name my-certificate --vault-name newcertkv
openssl pkcs12 -in newcert123.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out newcert123.pem -password pass:0000
```

[image]

```
openssl  pkcs12 -in newcert123.pfx -nocerts -out newcert123.key -password pass:XXXX
```

[image]